# What does "through the bag" mean?

Tags: meaning

> This golf ball can provide higher ball speeds and optimal spin rates
>   to maximize performance **through the bag**.

I searched dictionaries, but couldn't find any relevant result. Can anybody help me figure out what it means?

Comment: It's not an established collocation with a widely-recognised meaning, so I suggest it's best interpreted in the *exact* context of "golfing accessories" - which are mostly carried around in a golf bag. I'm guessing it's a "synecdoche" wherein the *[golf] **bag*** represents ***all*** actual physical *golfing equipment* (as opposed to more abstract things like ***skill, experience***, which might also be involved in maximising performance at golf). Essentially, with better equipment like this golf ball, you can play better golf.

Comment: [Chris Ryan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbZfRPw5-Ww) explains the concept (through the bag) as the clubs you have, i.e. starting with short irons, moving on to long irons, etc.

Comment: Meant to write starting with short-irons, moving on to mid-irons, then long-irons, etc.

Comment: In U.S. English, we might expect to see the underlying concept expressed as "throughout the bag"—that is, "with every club or iron in the bag."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a golf bag as a series of 10-12 different tools for solving a problem. There are many people who are really good with one of those tools, so much so that they use it in place of several of the other tools. This is a strategy, and it can work for some people.

But for most people, their best strategy is to get as good as they can with all the tools. This means building core strength for many of the irons, fine motor skills for putters, problem-solving (and occasional brute strength) for wedges, and solid aim for woods.

This is what it means to play through-the-bag, to utilize all the clubs for their designated uses and work through their individual peculiarities, rather than becoming super good at your nine-iron in hopes you can skip having to learn the complexities of wedges and woods.

Comment: So in context, do you read this sentence as meaning that the ball literally works well with any club, or is it more metaphorical than that?

Comment: Yes, I read it as the ball improving many different aspects of your play (as represented by the different clubs).

Answer (score 0):

(playing) **through the** (golf) **bag** =  one's golf game

As in:

> This golf ball optimizes your golf game: from the tee to the cup.

**golf bag**: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79822?redirectedFrom=golf%20bag#eid2840437)

1921   Daily Colonist (Victoria, Brit. Columbia)

> English **golf bag** and clubs, also violin, for sale.

As the game of golf proceeds, one goes **through the bag** using different clubs for the tee shot, the fairways, roughs, traps, to the green and then into the cup.